# In R, how to specify contrasts to compare weighted means of multiple groups in linear model?

Tags: r, statistics, categorical-data

I'm trying to use effects coding in a linear model to compare the *weighted means* of groups of unequal sample size against each other. In this dummy example, we have one group of 19 observations with mean 5.04, and two groups of 25 and 26 observations respectively, whose joint mean is 6.10.

How do I specify my contrasts such that I get a coefficient for the difference between those two means? See question marks in my code. The second contrast, to distinguish versicolor and virginica, is not of particular interest.

Note: I am not asking about unweighted contrasts, so not for example `contrasts(df$Species) <- matrix(c(.6666, -.3333, -.3333, 0, .5, -.5), ncol = 2)`

```
set.seed(5)
df <- iris[sample.int(nrow(iris), 70), c("Sepal.Length", "Species")]
table(df$Species)
mean(df$Sepal.Length[df$Species == "setosa"])
mean(df$Sepal.Length[!df$Species == "setosa"])
contrasts(df$Species) <- ???
res <- lm(Sepal.Length~Species, df)
stopifnot(mean(df$Sepal.Length[df$Species == "setosa"])-mean(df$Sepal.Length[!df$Species == "setosa"]) == coef(res)[2])
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly a little clunky:

```r
library(emmeans)
set.seed(5)
df <- iris[sample.int(nrow(iris), 70), c("Sepal.Length", "Species")]
res <- lm(Sepal.Length~Species, df)
ctr <- contrast(emmeans(res, "Species"), 
         list(weighted = c(1, -(25/51), -(26/51))))
```

Comment: Thank you Simon, but note that my question is specifically about how to specify the contrasts such that the linear model estimates this quantity directly, not about how to get the answer! It's a question about model specification..

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question; it seems that the matrix of contrasts must be inverted, and then it works:

```
set.seed(9)
n = 89
condition <- sample(c("nothing", "t-shirt", "chalk ball", "chalk powder", "liquid chalk"), n, replace = TRUE)
means <- c("nothing" = 25, "t-shirt" = 35, "chalk ball" = 27, "chalk powder" = 22, "liquid chalk" = 21)
hangtime <- means[condition] + rnorm(n, 0,10)
hangtime <- abs(hangtime)
chalk <- data.frame(condition = factor(condition, levels = c("nothing", "t-shirt", "chalk ball", "chalk powder", "liquid chalk")), hangtime = hangtime)

mat <- cbind(c(1/5,1/5,1/5,1/5,1/5),
             c(-1.5, -1.5, 1,1,1),
             c(-1,1, 0, 0, 0),
             c(0,0,-.5,-.5, 1),
             c(0,0,-1,1,0))
mat <- solve(t(mat))
mat <- mat[, -1]
cont <- contrasts(chalk$condition)
cont[,] <- mat
colnames(cont) <- c("nothingshirtVchalk", "nothingVshirt", "dryVliquid", "ballVpowder")
contrasts(chalk$condition) <- cont
summary(lm(hangtime~condition, chalk))
```